# API Outlook WordPress error

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a problem with the Outlook API. I have an error message:

```
An error occurred: unsupported_response_type
```

And

```
The provided value for the input parameter 'response_type' is not allowed for this client. Expected value is 'code'.
```

My code being too long, I can't show it to you.

I remain at your entire disposal if you need me.

I add my gitHub link https://github.com/bendubled/test-api

I mainly use the outlook-demo. js file 
https://github.com/bendubled/test-api/blob/master/wp-content/themes/themeLastConstitution/custom/js/outlook-demo.js
And the game. php file
https://github.com/bendubled/test-api/blob/master/wp-content/themes/themeLastConstitution/game.php
From line "123" onwards.
I'm trying to add the mail display to one of the tabs. Hopefully someone can help me, thank you all!!

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator

Comment: Please add more details to your question. Make a minimal example that reproduces the issue. Show us/explain what you are calling, what is the expected result? What data is being sent?

Comment: Hi, I just completed my post.